# How to set a layout in the middle of thescreen to show Image and text Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have some images from url data, which I want to show in a detail view of the app. To do that Ihave set a Liner Layout, and imageView inside the layout and the text for title. Bit the problem is the image is showinf at the top of the layout, not in the cenrer of the screen. How can I set the image in the middle of that layer and text below the image. Here is my XML code for that layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/detail_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="Hallo world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this use `RelativeLayout` insted of `LinearLayout` and

make your `ImageView` `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

make your `TextView` `android:layout_below="@id/detail_image"` like below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/detail_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/detail_image"
        android:text="Hallo world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: sorry I could not understant your second answer

Comment: Could you please also give an upvote to my question?

Answer (score 1):

```
Update xml file like this


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/detail_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Hallo world" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```